# Extract property of object from entity framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, iqueryable

I'm new to EF and I'm having trouble doing the simplest thing...

```
public class Person : DTO
{
    public String ID { get; set; }
    public String Fname { get; set; }
    public String Lname{ get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use either `IQueryable<Person>` or `ObjectReuslt<Person>` to extract `Fname` from my object.

```
 peopleEntities entities = new peopleEntities();
 string queryStr = "select value c from peopleEntity.Person as c Where c.ID=" + personID;
 IQueryable<EntityObject> query = entities.CreateQuery<EntityObject>(queryStr);
```

I see that `CreateQuery` can both return `IQueryable` and `ObjectResult`. I'd like to know whats the lightest way that I can extract `Fnames` into a list from my query result.

Comment: Why are you writing sql queries when using EF?  you lose all the strongly typed awesomeness that EF gets you

Comment: @Kritner Well, entity table name is supposed to be dynamic and I thought formatting sql string was the easiest. What do u think? Create query will not let me do something like... `select fname from peopleEntity.Person ...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your question as "Get the first name of the provided personId". Assuming your `peopleEntities` contains a `DbSet<Person> Person` you could do the following:

```
public string GetFirstNameForPeron(string personId)
{
    peopleEntities entities = new peopleEntities(); // new up your EF context

    return entities
        .Person // from the person entities
        .Where(w => w.ID == personId) // Where the ID = personId
        .FirstOrDefault(); // take the first available
        .Fname; // only the Fname property
}
```

Comment: So what if the entity `Person` and field `Fname` are dynamic. Meaning I don't know which entity I am dealing with, and also don't know the field I want.

Comment: That sounds like a very different scenario that what you're asking about in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084916/dynamically-select-columns-in-runtime-using-entity-framework