# Dynamically select properties in runtime using Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I need to call LINQ selector with dynamic property names.
But LINQ selector can not return data that exists in property names.

---

The following is simulated sample code from my problems:

```
public class DataService
{
    public record Data(int Id, string Name, string Title, string Comment);

    private static readonly IList<Data> datas;
    static DataService()
    {
        datas = new List<Data>();
        //*Fill datas from db or file or static codes*
    }
    public IList<Data> Get(params string[] selector)
    {
        return datas.Select(selector).ToList(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problems with following codes and use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77119079/13868870) .

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params string[] propertyNames) => source.AsQueryable().Select(propertyNames);
public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TResult>(this IQueryable<TResult> source, params string[] propertyNames)
{
    var resultType = typeof(TResult);
    var properties = resultType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty);
    var selectedProperties = properties.Where(p => propertyNames.Contains(p.Name) && p.CanWrite).ToList();

    var sourceType = source.ElementType;
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "e");
    var bindings = selectedProperties.Select(q => Expression.Bind(q, Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, q.Name))).ToList();

    var instance = Expression.New(resultType);
    var body = Expression.MemberInit(instance, bindings);

    var selector = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
    var quote = Expression.Quote(selector);
    var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", [sourceType, resultType], source.Expression, quote);
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(call);
}
```

Comment: This is *very* elaborate way to say that you liked an answer. Please just upvote answers instead of basically repeating them.