# Passing a method with parameter Func<T> and getting TResult

Tags: c#, generics, func, iasyncresult

So basically T has a return type, I want to get back the generic return type. Example:

```
private TResult EndInvoke<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> asyncCaller, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    TResult result = default(TResult);

    try
    {
        result = asyncCaller.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
       // get exception details.
    }

    return result;
}
```

How do I pass just the T calling the method and get the TResult?
Mind you, I only have the T.

**EDIT:** I meant how do I call  this method?

**EDIT:** I want a generic EndInvoke, because I am a huge try catch on different EndInvokes, then I want the result from the EndInvoke.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `So basically T has a return type` Actually, you have return type `TResult`. The question is unclear.

Comment: This function looks like its whole point (in combination with another function, probably named `BeginInvoke`) is to enable asynchronous calls. If you only have the `T`, want to call `asyncCaller`, and want to handle the result in that very same function, you can only use a synchronous call. Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. For a generic type, you need to either mention the type in the definition as the type parameter T or TResult.  If you just want to mention T and not TResult in method definition, how does it know what TResult can be? You can either use dynamic or object result type for that purpose.

Comment: You say you want a generic EndInvoke. You've got a generic EndInvoke. What is the problem you're having? After your next edit, please re-read your question, and see if you would understand what is being asked if someone else asked the question.

Comment: I suppose you could turn this into an extension method. Is that an acceptable solution?

Comment: @hvd: Please read the part: I meant how do I call this method?

Comment: @MilkTea027 Please read my earlier question. Calling this method makes no sense if you only have the `T`.

Comment: @hvd Then the method is wrongly implemented for the generic EndInvoke because I want a try catch around the generic EndInvoke then return the TResult.. To clarify.. What is the correct implementation then?

Comment: @MilkTea027 Oh wait... So you don't have a *value* of type `T`, you have the *type* `T`. A simple approach, if your goal is to make it work without having to know `TResult`, would be to simply use `Func<T, object>`. For functions that return a reference type, that means the functions themselves don't even need to change.

Comment: This question is melting my brain. Is the problem that you have a value of type `T` but can't determine the type of `TResult`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, here's the original question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822569/how-to-make-a-generic-delegate-endinvoke

Comment: In that question `T` is equal to `TResult`. Is that a coincidence?

Comment: No they are not equal.

Comment: What do you mean? The first delegate `GetFooAsync1` takes a parameter of type `Foo1` and returns a value of type `Foo1`. In other words: `T == TResult`.

Comment: The T I was trying to pass was GetFooAsync1, then I want it to return a Foo1

Comment: @MilkTea027 Then just call `EndInvoke(GetFooAsync1, asyncResult)`? The compiler should be able to figure out the correct `T` and `TResult` from that.

Comment: It doesn't work :( I need it to be generic, if it is possible?

Comment: @MilkTea027 Oh wait, sorry, yeah, that won't work, because you've got custom delegate types. You don't need custom delegate types, and if you remove them (instead using `Func<T, TResult>` everywhere), it would work.

Comment: @MilkTea027 Can you comment on my answer explaining why that's not what you need?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest converting your generic `EndInvoke<,>` method to an extension method first.

```
public static class FuncExtensions
{
    public static TResult EndInvoke<T, TResult>(this Func<T, TResult> asyncCaller, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will simplify the method call. As an example, I'll call a method that calculates the square of an integer.

```
private int Square(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

In your client code, you'd call it like this:

```
Func<int, int> caller = new Func<int, int>(Square);

int x = 5;

int y = default(int);

caller.BeginInvoke(x,
    asyncResult =>
    {
        y = caller.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
    },
    null);

Console.WriteLine("The square of {0} is {1}", x, y);
```

**EDIT**

This example has not been tested in any way, and contains an obvious race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand correctly, but I think that if you want the Func return value, you should drop the IAsyncResult.

Example:

```
private TResult GetResult<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> asyncCaller, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        TResult result = default(TResult);
        result = asyncCaller(argument...);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The name of the function in the question, `EndInvoke`, and the `IAsyncResult`, suggest an asynchronous call has already been made, though.