# Passing a lambda expression as parameter to a method?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, parameters, lambda

It seems like it'd be a common requirement, but I cannot find a solution to this anywhere.

I have a method which will `OrderBy` a collection depending on a parameter passed to it.

I'd like to pass the contents of an 'OrderBy' to the method, but cannot work out how to do it.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried a switch with a string (i.e. if you pass 'Name' it'll hit the `case` which orders it by name), but this feels 'hacky' and unnecessary.

I know it's something like `Func<TEntity, TResult>`, but I can't quite crack it.

PSEUDO CODE:

```
GetOrderedCollection([NOT SURE] orderBy)
{
  return collection.OrderBy(orderBy);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the parameter that OrderBy actually takes and use the same parameter type for your method?

Answer (score 3):

OrderBy is an extension method with the following signature:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

(source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx )

so your method needs a Func as its argument, where TSource is the List type, and TKey is the type returned by your lambda.
An example would be:

```
public void Method<TSource, TKey>(List<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TKey> func)
        {
            ...
            IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> orderedEnumerable = list.OrderBy(func);
        }
```

**EDIT:**
I also noticed that in your example code you declared your method as void, bu then you're trying to return an IOrderedEnumerable.
If you want to get the ordered collection back, your method needs to have at least an IEnumerable type (but that would defeat the purpose of ordering it, as IEnumerables do not guarantee order. A more likely implementation would be to return a `List<TSource>` and call `list.OrderBy(func).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

In it's most generic form, your method would need to look like:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<T1> GetOrderedCollection<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> collection, Func<T1, T2> orderBy)
{
    return collection.OrderBy(orderBy);
}
```

`T1` being the type of the items in the list and `T2` being the type of the property of `T1` that you want to order on.

Answer (score 0):

Does this satisfy your requirements?

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {           
        var objects = new List<Test>();
        GetOrderedCollection(objects, x => x.Name);
    }

    class Test {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static IEnumerable<TEntity> GetOrderedCollection<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> objects, Func<TEntity, object> orderBy) {
        return objects.OrderBy(orderBy);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are looking for a `Func<TEntity, TResult> orderingFunc`.  The important thing is that the output (the `TResult`) is an `IComparable` so that the `OrderBy` function can properly sort your results.

So something like this will work fine:

```
public void OrderByDynamic(Func<Model, object> orderByFunc)
{
    collection = collection.OrderBy(orderByFunc); //don't forget to assign the return value
}
```

You could call this with lambda functions like normal:

```
OrderByDynamic(m => m.SortObj); //as long as this property/return value is IComparable
```

[A .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a7C1ra) demonstrating this idea

Answer (score -1):

The parameter has to be either a `Func` or an `Action`. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297633/c-sharp-pass-lambda-expression-as-method-parameter) for more information.