# How to pass a lambda expression to a method expecting lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have an extension method to get a property name as string:

```
    public static string GetPropertyName<T, TResult>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> propertyId)
    {
        return ((MemberExpression)propertyId.Body).Member.Name;
    }
```

Now I have another method, expecting to pass in list (param) of this kind of property lamba expression.
I want this new method to reuse the 1st method, but can't figure out how to pass it over

```
    public string Test<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] ps)
    {
        foreach (var p in ps)
        {
                var howToCodeThis = p.GetPropertyName(dummy => dummy);
```

expected usage:

```
                var result = Test<Something>(request.Sorting
                , x => x.prop1
                , x => x.prop2
                , x => x.prop3
                );
```

Update:
Backs answer worked once I change my GetPropertyName to cater for UnaryExpression:

```
    public static string GetPropertyName<T, TResult>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> propertyId)
    {
        if (propertyId.Body is MemberExpression)
            return ((MemberExpression)propertyId.Body).Member.Name;

        if (propertyId.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var op = ((UnaryExpression)propertyId.Body).Operand;
            return ((MemberExpression)op).Member.Name;
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("GetPropertyName - {0}", propertyId.Body.GetType().FullName));
    }
```

Comment: I asked a very similar question not too long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734899/passing-a-lambda-expression-as-parameter-to-a-method

Comment: i voted up your question. i really hate ppl simply downvote a question without reason.

Comment: thanks. Downvotes are helpful if there's an explanation, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var howToCodeThis = GetPropertyName(default(T), p);
```

OR

```
var howToCodeThis = default(T).GetPropertyName(p);
```

But I noteced, you don't use `obj` in GetPropertyName method.

Comment: I think the reason `obj` is there is so that inferring type parameters works.

Comment: that method is an extension, such is the way of the coding syntax. using it is as such myObj.GetPropertyName(x => x.Prop)

Comment: I can only use 2nd option, as the method is an extension method. it doesn't work, giving error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression

Comment: the issue is due to my GetPropertyName. I posted an update about this, and yours answer worked.