# Pass lambda expression/anonymous method into BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, lambda, backgroundworker

Suppose I have a `BackgroundWorker` in my code. I want to pass anonymous function/delegate in it at start. The code bellow is what I want to do:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => {
    Func<string> f = (Func<string>)e.Argument;
    f("step one");
    ...
    f("step two");
}
bw.RunWorkerAsync((string txt) => {Console.WriteLine(txt);} ); // doesn't work
// bw.RunWorkerAsync( delegate(string txt) { Console.WriteLine(txt); })); // doesn't work too
```

The error:

> Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'object' because it is not a
>   delegate type

Or

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a
>   delegate type

So how can I passinto   lambda expression/anonymous method into `BackgroundWorker`?

Here is a code in C to describe exactly what I need:

```
void func(char *ch)
{
    printf("%s", ch);
}

void test( void (* f)(char *) )
{
    f("blabla");
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    test(func);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Pass Lambda Expression as Method Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297633/c-sharp-pass-lambda-expression-as-method-parameter)

Comment: Your code has a `Func<string> f` type which you are calling with a string. This won't compile as `f` is a function which takes nothing and returns a string. You need `Action<string> f`.

Comment: Assign it to a variable and pass it as a parameter `Action<string> obj = Console.WriteLine;
bw.RunWorkerAsync(obj);` Yes, you need `Action<string>` not `Func<string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the lambda to a variable and then pass it in:

```
Action<string> action = (string txt) => Console.WriteLine(txt);
bw.RunWorkerAsync(action);
```

Note that I've used an `Action<>` as your code takes data and doesn't return anything. Your `DoWork` handler is wrong and should be like this:

```
bw.DoWork += (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => {
    Action<string> f = (Action<string>)e.Argument;
    f("step one");
    ...
    f("step two");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sean that's exactly what I need. And yes, I've written  `Func<string>` just for example to describe my target.