# Argument Type Not assignable using Lambda parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to apologize in advance for not connecting the dots to understand the big picture.

This method is a violation of DRY and has a common use 3rd party library that might normally be called like:

```
ThirdLibrary.DoWork(x => x.Blah....);
```

In trying to refactor this method I wanted this line and some others near it extracted to a separate method....but I needed to pass in the lambda and Google led me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297633/c-sharp-pass-lambda-expression-as-method-parameter) and [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396746/c-sharp-lambda-expressions-as-function-arguments)

My difficulty is translating to my exact situation with a third party library.

The third party metadata shows it is expecting:

```
public IDoWork<T> DoWork(Expression<Action<T>> expression);
```

I'm stumbling on how to parameterize this for my method.

```
public void RepoDoWork(Action<ICustomerRepository> doworkrule)
{
   ThirdLIbrary.DoWork(doworkrule);
}
```

This produces the error Argument type is not assignable to parameter type.

Thank you for your assistance in helping me understand how to pass lambdas correctly.

Comment: What exactly does `ThirdLibrary.DoWork()` take?

Comment: Which part violates DRY?  The `x => x` part?  I would not worry about that.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for - method asks for expression and you try to pass delegate... Why can't you pass `Expression` to start with?

Comment: @DStanley...it was a snip. For brevity I didn't include all the other stuff being extracted.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov...because I have not been edjumakated on Expression...I am googling now.

Comment: The answer is to use `ThirdLIbrary.DoWork(t => doworkrule(t));`  If you think that violates DRY you are taking the principle to the extreme.

Comment: Expression<TDelegate> was the answer. @AlexeiLevenkov make your comment an answer and I'll be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method asks for `Expression<...>` and you try to pass delegate - there is no useful conversion so that would fail.

To fix you should pass proper `Expression` to your helper and that to the third party method.

You can try to wrap delegate into expression but in most cases it will not produce useful results at run time. Usually when method takes an expression it means it will deconstruct expression in some way and build logic based on it. Common examples  are LINQ-to-SQL constructing SQL queries based on lambdas based to `Queryable.Where(...)` calls or Moq framework using expressions for setting up method mocks.